# Is a RegularExpressionValidator reliable enough to protect against SQL injections?

Tags: .net, vb.net, validation, sql-injection

I'm using a tool that helps to know what parts of my code are open to SQL injection and the tool in question indicates there is a vulnerability in the following code :

Aspx part:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fuXlsWorkflow" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="<%$ Resources:Message,ERR_FORMAT%>"ValidationExpression="^([a-zA-Z]|\x20|\x2E|:|\\|[0-9])*\.(xls|xlsx)$" ControlToValidate="fuXlsWorkflow" />
```

aspx.vb

```
If Not fuXlsWorkflow.FileName.Equals("") Then
    If xlsFile Is Nothing Or Not fuXlsWorkflow.FileName.Equals(xlsFile) Then
        xlsFileTempPath = SantEnv.TempFolder & " " & fuXlsWorkflow.FileName
        fuXlsWorkflow.SaveAs(SantEnv.TempFolder & " " & fuXlsWorkflow.FileName)
        Try
            getIdApplicationFromXls()
            ...
```

And

```
Private Sub getIdApplicationFromXls()
    Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection
    Dim myCommand As OleDbDataAdapter
    dsIdApplication = New Data.DataSet()
    Try
        myConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=" & SantEnv.ExcelProvider & ";Data Source=" + xlsFileTempPath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1'")
        myCommand = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", myConnection)
        myCommand.Fill(dsIdApplication)
    Catch ex As Exception
        cvError.Text = ex.Message
        cvError.IsValid = False
        Throw New Exception(ex.Message, ex)
    End Try
            ...
```

Basically, i use the filename to open a OleConnection and it seems to be a problem according to the tool i'm using. What i don't understand is the `asp:RegularExpressionValidator` should already prevent the user from uploading a file with a suspicious name.

What would you recommend to avoid having that warning in my tool when it comes to that block of code ?

EDIT:
This is what the tool writes me :

> The application's getIdApplicationFromXls method executes an SQL query
> with mycommand, at line 201 of workflow\workflowList.aspx.vb. The
> application constructs this SQL query by embedding an untrusted string
> into the query without proper sanitization. The concatenated string is
> submitted to the database, where it is parsed and executed
> accordingly.
>
> The attacker would be able to inject arbitrary data into the SQL
> query, by simply altering the user input filename, which is read by
> the EnvoieFichier_Click method at line 151 of
> workflow\workflowList.aspx.vb. This input then flows through the code
> to the database server, without sanitization.
>
> This may enable an SQL Injection attack.

Comment: Instead of relying one the regular expression evaluator, check the existence of the Excel file before using the filename.

Comment: Also your regex is a an unnecessarily long-winded way of saying `^[a-zA-Z .0-9]*\.xlsx?$`, which can be further compressed into `(?i)[a-z .0-9]+\.xlsx?`. The anchors `^` and `$` are superfluous because regular expression validators only take the full string into account anyway. The `(?i)` makes the expression case-insensitive, and using `+` instead of `*` makes sure there is at least *one* character before the file extension.

Comment: I wonder how the tool would react to the OleDbConnectionStringBuilder. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbconnectionstringbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0 The warning message seems strange because there is no embedded string in the command.